# Mysql: Selecting one table and limiting row result for each column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some MySQL query that i have been working on since yesterday, which i was not able to correct. I have also been looking through alot of search in google as well as here in stackoverflow which i still can't find a viable solution.

In my problem, i have this one table Users, which has a column: id, name, gender, city, citizenship. The table contains a thousands of records.

The table looks something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
| id | name | gender | city | citizenship |
-------------------------------------------
| 1 | alfred | m | new york | american    |
-------------------------------------------
| 2 | benny | f | london | british        |
-------------------------------------------
| 3 | george | m | brisbane | australian  |
-------------------------------------------
| 4 | itachi | m | tokyo | japanese       |
-------------------------------------------
| 5 | jenny | f | lauderdale | american   |
-------------------------------------------
```

etc... around a thousand records..

Now my problem is, i want to query that only table (Users) base on a certain criteria.

For example, i wanted to query atleast 50 males and 50 females, that is overall 100 records.

Which also needs, that some User, atleast 30 of them are in new york, another 30 of them are in london, another 40 of them are in brisbane. still overall 100 records.

Which also needs, regardless of which city they are in, that some user has a citizenship atleast 60 of them are americans, 20 british and 20 australian.

This is my current query i have tried, something like this, with a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT gender as genderMale
        FROM users 
        WHERE gender = 'M'
        LIMIT 50
    ) AS myMale,

    (
        SELECT gender as genderFemale
        FROM users 
        WHERE gender = 'F'
        LIMIT 50
    ) AS myFemale,

    (
        SELECT city as cityNewYork
        FROM users 
        WHERE city = 'new york'
        LIMIT 30
    ) AS myCityNewYork,

    (
        SELECT city as cityLondon
        FROM users 
        WHERE city = 'london'
        LIMIT 30
    ) AS myLondon,

    (
        SELECT city as cityBrisbane
        FROM users 
        WHERE city = 'brisbane'
        LIMIT 40
    ) AS myBrisbane
```

and so on for the citizenship.. etc..

The result also yielded more than what i wanted.

Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL?

Your help is gladly appreciated.

Thank you

---

UPDATE: SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/499874

Comment: This is quite hard to arrange in SQL, simply because it might not be possible.  There may be no subset that meets your conditions at the same time.

Comment: 'The result also yielded more than what i wanted.' - how many did you expect AND are each of these requirements independent?You could chop the numbers down to a more manageable sample and add sample data.

Comment: @P.Salmon hello thank you for the comment, atleast the result would be the nearest sum of the criteria, for example a 50 males and 50 females, that would atleast yielded 100 or so, but atleast nearest to the sum.

Comment: @P.Salmon may i know if you can add a comment to add the overall sample data? so i could have some idea please. thank you

Comment: You can just edit the question or you can create a sqlfiddle.

Comment: @P.Salmon i just updated the question with sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/499874